# How to avoid viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange() being called in UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, safearealayoutguide

I have a child-view controller that do not want to have system safe areas or `viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange()` called on rotation. So far this is not working:

In Superview:

```
let childVC = UIViewController()
self.addChild(childVC)
childVC.view.frame = CGRect(x:0, y: self.view.bounds.height - 300, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: 300)
self.view.addSubview(childVC.view)
childVC.didMove(toParent: self)
```

In Child View Controller:

```
class childVC: UIViewController {
    let picker = UIPickerView()
    
    override final func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
    
        self.viewRespectsSystemMinimumLayoutMargins = false
        self.view.insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea   = false
        self.view.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins.  = false
    }

    override final func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        //Some mention this to be inside viewDidAppear
        self.viewRespectsSystemMinimumLayoutMargins = false
        self.view.insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea = false
        self.view.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false

        //Add picker view here
        self.picker.delegate = self
        self.picker.dataSource = self
        self.picker.frame = self.view.bounds
        self.view.addSubview(self.picker)
    }

    override func viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange() {
        super.viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange()
        //This gets called everytime the device rotates, causing the picker view to redraw and reload all components. Trying to avoid this method being called.

        print ("viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange")
        print (self.view.safeAreaInsets)
    }
}
```

### Issue

Everytime the device rotates, `viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange()` gets called causing the picker view to redraw and reload.

### Goal

Trying to avoid `viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange()` being called every time the device rotates.

Comment: I would be surprised that `viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange()` is what's actually triggering the picker view reload. Can you post enough code to **show** that's the cause of the reload?

Comment: For example, this code: https://pastebin.com/vLkNj6vy. ... adds a picker view at a specific rect - no resizing on rotation - and the `.dataSource` / `.delegate` funcs are only called on initial load and when scrolling the picker. They are **not** called on device rotation.

Comment: `viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange()` doesn't get called in an iPhone SE and the picker does not get reloaded.

Comment: If we focus on `viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange()` to not to get called, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Tough to say what's going on just looking at your snippets... can you provide testable code?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot post more. I would like to get to the bottom of why safe areas are still a factor...

Comment: @Gizmodo don't call the super function here:
override func viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange() {

        print ("viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange")
        print (self.view.safeAreaInsets)
    }

Comment: @Gizmodo - you could at least post enough code to show what you are *trying* to do. Just using the `addChild` code you included, the picker view disappears on device rotation - which, I'm guessing, is not your goal. As I showed in the sample code I linked to, `viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange()` ***DOES*** get called, but ***DOES NOT*** cause the picker view to reload its data. Also, in **this** code (loading picker in a child controller): https://pastebin.com/cZPTZ17C ... again, `viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange()` ***DOES*** get called, but ***DOES NOT*** cause the picker view to reload.

Comment: Yes, let me get back with more code.

Comment: I had the view move around with frame changes and noticed whenever`viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange()` gets called, UIPickerView gets reloaded. So I need to figure out a way to stop `viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange()` from being called.

Comment: @Gizmodo - I *really, **really, REALLY*** believe you are chasing your tail. `viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange()` is a *notification* sent to the controller. It is not what is ***causing*** the picker view reload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange()`

> Called to notify the view controller that the safe area insets of its root view changed.

This is a *notification* call. You ignore it, or respond to it... but you cannot **prevent** the safe area insets from changing.

These two examples: https://pastebin.com/vLkNj6vy and https://pastebin.com/cZPTZ17C show that `viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange()` **is called** on device rotation, but the picker view **does NOT** reload.

The picker view will reload if its frame is **outside** the affected safe-area change.

Here is a quick example:

```
class MovingPickerVC: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {
    
    let picker = UIPickerView()
    
    var vConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = []
    var hConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        picker.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(picker)

        // keep picker INSIDE the safe-area
        //  this WILL NOT cause reload on device rotation
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        // extend picker frame OUTSIDE the safe-area
        //  this WILL cause reload on device rotation
        //let g = self.view!
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            picker.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300.0),
            picker.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 160.0),
        ])

        vConstraints = [
            picker.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            picker.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
        ]
        hConstraints = [
            picker.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
            picker.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
        ]

        // so we can see its frame
        picker.backgroundColor = .yellow
        
        self.picker.delegate = self
        self.picker.dataSource = self
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        if self.traitCollection.verticalSizeClass == .regular {
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(vConstraints)
        } else {
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(hConstraints)
        }
    }
    
    override func willTransition(to newCollection: UITraitCollection, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.willTransition(to: newCollection, with: coordinator)
        
        coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { [unowned self] _ in
            if newCollection.verticalSizeClass == .regular {
                NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(self.hConstraints)
                NSLayoutConstraint.activate(self.vConstraints)
            } else {
                NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(self.vConstraints)
                NSLayoutConstraint.activate(self.hConstraints)
            }
        }) { [unowned self] _ in
            // if we want to do something on completion
        }
        
    }
    override func viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange() {
        super.viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange()
        //This gets called everytime the device rotates, causing the picker view to redraw and reload all components. Trying to avoid this method being called.
        
        print ("viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange")
        print (self.view.safeAreaInsets)
    }
    
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        print("num components: 1")
        return 1
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        print("num rows: 30")
        return 30
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        print("Title for Row:", row)
        return "Row: \(row)"
    }
    
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

and rotating the device:

[image]

When that is run, we **will** see the `viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange()` being logged, but the picker view **will NOT** reload.

However, in `viewDidLoad()`, if we change the constraints to the **view** instead of the **safe area**:

```
    // keep picker INSIDE the safe-area
    //  this WILL NOT cause reload on device rotation
    //let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
    
    // extend picker frame OUTSIDE the safe-area
    //  this WILL cause reload on device rotation
    let g = self.view!
```

[image]

[image]

we've placed the picker view frame outside the safe area, and it **will** reload on rotation.

If you don't want the picker to reload (for some reason), you'll need to manage that via your dataSource / delegate funcs.

Comment: You did an amazing job explaining this! Thank you!